# How to redirect to views path in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-8

I have created a views in Drupal 8 and set the path as candidates in PAGE SETTINGS.

In Drupal 7 drupal_goto('candidates');

What is the equivalent statement in Drupal 8?

Please help!...

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to a View like this :

return $this->redirect('view.MACHINE_NAME_VIEW.MACHINE_NAME_DISPLAY');

MACHINE_NAME_VIEW -> Located in the list of your Views.

MACHINE_NAME_DISPLAY -> Located in the Advanced tab and look at "Other".

It's probably better than using the path. If you change the path in the page settings of the view you don't have to change the redirect later.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example: It will work :)

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;
$form_state->setRedirect('view.VIEW_MACHINE_NAME.PAGE_MACHINENAME'); // view.my_view.page_1
```